# LED Matrix to reduce current consumption

Tags: transistors, current-limiting, usb-device, led-matrix

[image: Led matrix arrangement]

I'm trying to control RGB LEDs via USB. All LEDs have the same color, so I'm controlling them with only 3 PWM signals (generated from a PIC).
The problem I'm facing is to reduce the current needed in order to satisfy the USB specification.
There are in total 25 RGB LEDs (maybe more in the future) so I split them in 5 columns.

My questions:

- Are the selected transistors okay?
- The 5 V provided by the USB is enough to drive 2 transistors, 1
  limiter resistor and the LEDs? If not what could be a suitable alternative?
- How can I calculate the resistor values?
- Are R10-12 needed? I saw a lot of schematics with similar
  configurations without them.
- Is this the best solution for what I want to achieve?

I saw a lot of schematics and projects with an LED matrix, but their objective is to control all LEDs individually and I only want to reduce the max current.

I'm using SMD LEDs with the following forward voltages:

- Red: 1.6 V
- Green: 2.37 V
- Blue: 2.6 V

Datasheets:

- [STMicroelectronics TIP32C](https://pdf1.alldatasheet.com/datasheet-pdf/view/25376/STMICROELECTRONICS/TIP32C.html)
- [Freescale BC548C](https://pdf1.alldatasheet.com/datasheet-pdf/view/2897/MOTOROLA/BC548C.html)

Comment: Without knowing anything about the LEDs, none of your questions can be answered.

Comment: Please provide links to the manufacturer's datasheets for all of your transistors and for the LEDs. How much current do you intend to pass through the LEDs? Have you purchased LEDs that are binned for the same forward voltage?

Comment: I added transistors datasheet and LEDs forward voltages to the post. Unfortunately I don't have the data of LEDs manufacturers.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "All LEDs have the same color" if they are common-cathode RGB LEDs?  **What is the maximum amount of current that will be flowing through the LEDs at any instant in time?**

Comment: Where exactly is the PWM signal fed into this circuit? You have a total of 8 transistors...how is each of them driven? Which may be active at the same time?

Comment: What I meant is that all RGB LEDs will be controlled together, I don't want to control each individually RGB LED. If 1 RGB LED is purple, the rest will be purple as well.
And with the current: I always feed LEDs with ~10mA. Given that I want to multiplex, thought that 15mA would be fine.

The PWM signals fed isn't in the schematic because it isn't necessary for the question. The PWM signals go in the base of the respective BC548C transistors.
I conected every transistor to a power source only to measure the current flowing through the circuit. I updated the schematic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your circuit is logically good but I fear the duty cycle of 1/15 (max) per column is too thin to light the LEDs bright enough.

The simplest solution would be to drive all LEDs of one color at once, with a much fatter duty cycle, so let’s see if that works.

In the circuit below all LEDs of one color are controlled by one transistor and their max brightness set by one resistor and the duty cycle is 1/3.

[image]

For your desired 40 LEDs per color you can drive each at 10mA.
That’s 400mA, leaving 100mA for the rest of the circuit (to fit in the USB power budget of 500mA).

The max brightness would be an LED driven with 10mA at 1/3 duty cycle.
Dimming would be done with that same 10mA at a narrower duty cycle under software control.

The transistors only need to pass 400mA (at a worst case 1/3 duty cycle) so don’t have to be particularly beefy.

You’d choose R1, R2, R3 to get 10*40mA when fully on, taking into account the diode drop and choice of VCC.

The “10mA” is only a starting point to get in the ballpark.

You may find the red LEDs are more efficient and can get by with less, allowing the other colors to get more. Just need to make sure the three columns add up to 400mA (or whatever your margin is).

You may find you can push the max beyond the 500mA spec. If you’re only making one of these and it works in your system, go for it. But you could never do that for a production unit.

A large cap somewhere would be a good idea, to smooth out the rather large current spikes.

If the 400mA is too much of your power budget, you could double the columns, 20 LEDs each, maybe 15mA through each (300mA). But the duty cycle would only be 1/6.

Good luck. Fun project!

Comment: Thank you so much! I'm using now a resistor per LED, but I think is better to switch back to only one resistor per color.
¿Driving only one color at a time wouldn't make the mix color look a bit wrong? Anyway I'm gonna try that.
No matter what aproach I take it doesn't look so much scalable. Maybe I should look for some low current LED.

Answer (score 1):

R10 R11 and R12 are the primary current limiters for your leds per color respectfully. Without them, your really looking at burning the leds out because 5V is much higher than the nominal forward voltage at the nominal forward current for your leds. (I am going to assume 20mA @ the listed voltages, but those voltages seem low).

With that said, these single shared current limiter resistors will roughly limit each color section to 25mA for green and blue and 35mA for red. Since you have 25 leds per color in parallel, that means each led, if all of the low side transistors are on, will share the current at about 1 mA each. If only one is on, then it is about 5mA each. Assuming 100% everything on, and eyeballing the transistor current, you are looking at right around 100mA.

This would get you at the USB spec for unenumerated devices. But no one cares about that part of the spec to be honest. USB is just a ubiquitous 5V supply, often directly tied to the 5V rail and without limits. And your leds will be super dim. And that's before you start scanning through them or pwm. And if you are using a pic with usb, you can enumerate anyway and request the full current (500mA or more). So that's not a concern.

At these or even usable currents, any general purpose transistor will work. 2n3904 and 2n3906, 2n2222 etc. You may want to look at logic level mosfets if current is a concern. Those are just voltage operated.

You can easily increase the current by 5 times if you needed to.

Comment: Thanks for answer. The idea is only have on one column at time to reduce power consumption. Now only have 25 RGB LEDs but I want to have up to 40, that is 120 total LEDs. If every LED have around 5mA that would be more than the 500mA maximum provided by USB, thats why I want to multiplex.
An apologize if I didn't make it clear.
Now I'm using 2n2222 as you suggested with a resistor per LED.
My inicial doubt was if the 5 V from USB is enough voltage drop for the 2 transistors with the resistor and LED.